# Pre-done SQLs to be converted to Rails' style moduls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, legacy-database

I am a Rails newbie and would really appreciate if someone converted these SQLs to complete modules for rails. I know its a lot to ask but I can't just use find_by_sql for all of them. Or can I?

These are the SQLs (they run on MS-SQL):

`SELECT STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA.STA_ID, 
       STP_DATE, 
       STP_TIME, 
       STA_OPIS, 
       STA_SIFRA, 
       STA_POND FROM   STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA
    INNER JOIN STANJA_NA_DAN ON(STANJA_NA_DAN.STA_ID=STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA.STA_ID) 
WHERE ((OSE_ID=10)AND (STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA.STP_DATE>={d '2010-03-30'}) 
AND   (STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA.STP_DATE<={d '2010-03-30'}))`

`SELECT ZIGI_OBDELANI.OSE_ID,

       ZIGI_OBDELANI.DOG_ID AS DOG_ID,

       ZIGI_OBDELANI.ZIO_DATUM AS DATUM,

       ZIGI_PRICETEK.ZIG_TIME_D AS ZIG_PRICETEK,

       ZIGI_KONEC.ZIG_TIME_D AS ZIG_KONEC

FROM  (ZIGI_OBDELANI 
       INNER JOIN ZIGI ZIGI_PRICETEK 
         ON  ZIGI_OBDELANI.ZIG_ID_PRICETEK = ZIGI_PRICETEK.ZIG_ID )

INNER JOIN  ZIGI ZIGI_KONEC ON  ZIGI_OBDELANI.ZIG_ID_KONEC = ZIGI_KONEC.ZIG_ID

WHERE  (ZIGI_OBDELANI.OSE_ID = 10) 
AND    (ZIGI_OBDELANI.ZIO_DATUM >= {d '2010-03-30'}) 
AND    (ZIGI_OBDELANI.ZIO_DATUM <= {d '2010-03-30'}) 
AND    (ZIGI_PRICETEK.ZIG_VELJAVEN <> 0) 
AND    (ZIGI_KONEC.ZIG_VELJAVEN <> 0)

ORDER BY ZIGI_OBDELANI.OSE_ID, ZIGI_PRICETEK.ZIG_TIME ASC`

These SQLs are daily working hours and I got them as is. Also I got Database with it which (as you can see from the SQL-s) is not in Rails conventions.
As a P.S.:

1. Things like 
   STP_DATE>={d'2010-03-30'}) 
   are of course dates
   (in Slovenian date notation) and
   will be replaced with a variable
   (date), so that the user could
   choose date from and date to.
2. All of this data will be shown in
   the same page in the table,so maybe
   all in one module? Or many?; if this
   helps, maybe.

So can someone help me? Its for my work and its my 1st project and I am a Rails newbie and the bosses are getting inpatient(they are getting quite loud actually)

Thank you very very much!

So again I would really apreciate if someone could do a relevant model part for at least one of the complicated SQLs. I will read all the data in one controller and in one action. All will be done in one run.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Rails way to handle this, is to create models for each table, and create the relations inside the model.

Since it is a legacy-model you will have to do the following

```
class Stanja < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'STANJA_NA_DAN'
  set_primary_key 'your-primary-key'
end

class Postavka < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'STANJA_NA_DAN_POSTAVKA'
  set_primary_key 'STA_ID'
  has_many :stanjas, :foreign_key => 'sta_id', :primary_key => 'sta_id'
end
```

something like that. Without knowing your model and what the hell your table-names mean :)
But i hope it gets you started.

Success!!

Answer (score 0):

create views for these sqls in the database and a model for each view.

Comment: Can't because peaces like {d '2010-03-30'}) are included by application. These SQLs are just examples for one particular case. In reality dates and user id's (for example OSE_ID=10) are inputted by user

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the place to ask people to "Do my work for me" there are other sites like rent-a-coder where you can do that.

This is a place to ask for help however and I can give you some pointers.

The first thing you should do is start to work out what your models are. You could try auto-generating your models using [Dr Nics magic models](http://github.com/drnic/dr-nic-magic-models) though I expect that the fact that the database does not follow ActiveRecord conventions may be a problem for you.

I have had some success in the past with legacy databases by renaming the tables and columns to Rails conventions and providing a view that reflects the current naming convention for the existing legacy applications to use. If you were able to do that then your life would be easier as you could then use generators like Magic Models or [Ryan Bates nifty scaffold](http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) to provide you a basic structure to then start working on.

Hope this helps and good luck with your project.

Comment: This is why I said its difficult. I don't need the work done for me. I need an example of at least one of the complicated SQLs I wrote up converted so that I can model the rest on it. All the other text I wrote in was as a help so that people would know what's it about. Also I did took a look at 'Dr Nics magic models' previously I wrote this but don't believe  it helps in this case.
Also I have a basic structure but its all done with SQLs not at all in Rails style. Its done as I would do it in c++ Application. All manually.